# Sustain pedal information in recorded Midi?

Tags: midi, digital-piano, sustain

I realize this is a pretty model-specific question, but Reddit has amazed me before with its answers.

I have an old Yamaha DGX-620, that I'm using to do some composing. I've been using the song recording feature, and I'm able to save my songs as MIDI files to a USB drive. However, the sustain pedal completely ignored in the MIDI file: the song plays as if I hadn't used the pedal at all, with some notes much too short. Note that everything sounds fine when I play the songs back on the keyboard, it's just on the MIDI that it's missing.

I'm wondering, is there a setting I can change so that the sustain pedal information is included in the MIDI? Perhaps using the pedal to alter the note lengths, instead of storing it as separate information that doesn't end up in the MIDI?

Answer (score 3):

After importing into [Rosegarden](https://www.rosegardenmusic.com/tour/), it revealed that the pedal information was, in fact, stored in the Midi, so the problem was the program I was using to play it (in this case, LMMS).